# Induced subgraphs (graph theory)

Tags: graph-theory

I have the following graph theory question that I am stuck on:

Prove or disprove:
For every graph G and every integer $r \geq \text{max} \{\text{deg}v: v \in V(G) \}$ , there is an r-regular graph H containing G as an induced subgraph. Thanks for any help.

Comment: Something is missing here: is it "every integer $r \geq \max_{v \in G} \mathrm{deg}(v)$"?  This can be typeset using the code `$r \geq \max_{v \in G} \mathrm{deg}(v)$`.

Comment: I think that is required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you construct an r-regular graph with an arbitrary number of vertices as long as the number of vertices exceeds a given quantity? If so, then you may construct H from G as follows:

Let be the degree of the nth vertex of G. For every vertex in G with degree less than r, add a vertex to the graph and an edge connecting that vertex to and repeat this process until the degree of is r. Then you will have a graph in which the degree of the vertices originally in G is r, and the degree of the vertices not originally in G is 1. If you cannot construct an (r-1)-regular graph with the number of additional vertices (the ones not originally in G), then add two vertices and connect them with an edge. Repeat this process until you can construct an (r-1)-regular graph with the number of additional vertices. Now, for the vertices whose degree is 1, add the edges of the (r-1)-regular graph you constructed. This will complete the creation of H, and G will be an induced subgraph of H, which is seen easily by choosing the vertices originally in G, to which no edges were added in the creation of H.

Comment: Yes you need $r \geq \text{max}\{ \text{deg}v: v \in V(G) \}$

Comment: Anent the question on the first line of your answer, recall that if $r$ is odd then you can't have an $r$-regular graph with an odd number of vertices.

Comment: This can be resolved by noting that the number of new vertices is $2(rv-e)$ by the [Handshaking Lemma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Handshaking_lemma) (here v and e are the number of vertices and edges in G).  Since $2(rv-e)$ is even, this situation does not arise.  We also need to acknowledge the existence of r-regular graphs on an even number of vertices exists for a sufficiently large number of vertices (this can be achieved by looking at circulant graphs).  Also unaddressed is how to ensure the addition of the (r-1)-regular graph does not overlap the added edges.

Comment: @Rebecca Overlapping the added edges is easily avoided. The subgraph on the added vertices has even order, and all vertices have degree $0$ or $1$. Choose a proper $2$-coloring with an even number of vertices of each color. Construct an $(r-1)$-regular graph on the blue vertices, and another $(r-1)$-regular graph on the red vertices.

Answer (score 0):

Let $G$ be a graph with maximum degree $\le r$. Let the vertices of $G$ of degree $\lt r$ be listed (with repetitions) in a sequence $v_1,v_2,\dots,v_n$ where each vertex $v$ occurs $r-\mathrm{deg}(v)$ many times. (So $n=pr-2q$ where $p$ is the number of vertices and $q$ the number of edges in $G$.) Take $r$ vertex-disjoint copies $G^{(1)},G^{(2)},\dots,G^{(r)}$ of $G$; let $v_i^{(j)}$ be the copy of $v_i$ in $G^{(j)}$. Create new vertices $w_1,w_2,\dots,w_n$ and edges joining each $w_i$ to $v_i^{(1)},v_i^{( 2)},\dots,v_i^{(r)}$. Now we have an $r$-regular graph of order $2pr-2q$ containing $G$ as an induced subgraph.